# How do I add two sided arrow in this chain of commutative diagram?

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I want to build a chain of commutative diagram

I did get the code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187444/interpunction-and-tikz-diagrams) for building the commutative diagram. This is the code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
%\newcommand{\nospaceperiod}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\,}}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
V_1 \arrow{r} \arrow{d}{f_1} &
  V_2    \arrow{r} \arrow{d}{f_2} &
 \cdots \arrow{r} &
  V_{n-1} \arrow{r}    \arrow{d}{f_{n-1}} &
  V_n \arrow{d}{f_n}
\\
W_1 \arrow{r} &
 W_2      \arrow{r} &
 \cdots      \arrow{r} &
  W_{n-1} \arrow{r} &
W_n
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

which gives this output

[image]

I am almost done. I just want to know what do I change in `\arrow{r}` to make the right arrow to be two sided arrow or hook arrow or curved arrow.

I want output to look like these

[image: chain of Commutative diagram]

[image: Curved arrow]

Please share some manual that gives different keywords for different kind of arrows.

Comment: Simply use an option to arrow: `\arrow[<->]{r}`.

Comment: To bend the arrow: `\arrow[bend right]{r}` or `\arrow[bend left]{r}`.

Comment: Thank you.. \arrow[<->]{r} works.

But how do add a curved arrow from one variable to other surpassing one or more middle variables.. Like in the last diagram above ?

Comment: Use `r` twice: `\arrow[bend right]{rr}`

Comment: That works well :) Thank you

Comment: @Sigur Would you like to add an answer?

Comment: I will add that.

Answer (score 3):

For two sided arrow, simply replace it by: `\arrow[<->]{r}`.

To bend the arrow, use: `\arrow[bend right]{r}` or `\arrow[bend left]{r}`

Use `\arrow[bend right]{rr}`to point the curved arrow to next but one variable.

To get the output as in last image, use this code

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,bbm,amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
I    \arrow{r}{s}
     \arrow[bend right]{rr}{\mathbbm{1}} &
X^c  \arrow{r}{p}                        &
I 
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```